# Deleted example hardly noticable in proposal diff

Tags: feature-request, documentation, proposed-changes

When I [deleted an example and copy-pasted into a new one to reorder the examples](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/116987?filter-tags=c%2B%2B) (I second the motion to add a feature that does that), I noticed that in the proposal diff window, the deleted example was highlighted in a very faint red. I didn't notice it myself at first. The average newbie wouldn't either and then would think I simply duplicated an example. Perhaps make it more noticeable by putting like a "DELETED" label on top or making the red a little darker? I know the developers have much more pressing issues to attend to, but then again, this would involve simply changing a color value in a single web page.

Comment: have a screenshot?

Comment: Does the screenshot have a freehand red circle?

Comment: Examples don’t have an order. They’re ordered by votes.

Comment: Also be sure this isn't your monitor. With improperly set contrast or a color offset there can be no or little difference in value between white and various near white tints. I was wondering why the grey background of code markdown went away on my work monitor until I checked that.

Comment: I have a solid opinion that anyone who does design for screens would sleep easier if we could just get everyone to calibrate their monitor.

Comment: @gelliott181 I tried to calibrate my monitor... it didn't end well so I used the defaults.

Comment: I'm not sure how comfortable I am with a single massive cut-&-paste edit like this. From the *system's point of view*, you have effectively claimed ownership of a significant amount of content that was contributed by other people. There are licensing concerns regarding doing this (deciphering who originated the content is, at best, difficult) and deprives users from gaining reputation from the content they contributed. Example: [Ami Tavory added content](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/72011?filter-tags=c%2b%2b) which you (cont')

Comment: (cont') copied into [Ordered Associative Containers (std::set, std::multiset, std::map, std::multimap)](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/783/standard-library-containers/2690). The system does not consider [Ami Tavory as a contributor to this example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/revisions/783?exampleId=2690). In my opinion, this deprives that user (and possibly others) of the "appropriate credit" required by the CC BY-SA 3.0 license. I believe it was not your *intent* to do so, but is the effect of such edits (cont')

Comment: (cont'). There should be a way for the system to maintain the attribution/contributor list from examples which are merged, or split. Without such an automatic method, I would argue that it is *your* responsibility to explicitly give credit, in the example, to any and all users whose contribution you effectively usurp. This means you need to do the research to determine whose contributions you are moving, prior to doing so. This would at least provide them with "appropriate credit", but not the reputation for their contribution.